# Remove unused CSS from Semantic UI React

Tags: css, reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

Is there a way to remove the unused CSS imported from semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css?

Checking the Coverage tab in Developer Tools, it seems that this file contains 97.8% unused bytes.

Coverage tab image below:
[image]

Comment: You could use a tool like `PurgeCSS` in your build process to remove the unused `CSS` - https://purgecss.com

Comment: I tried to use PurgeCSS but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by importing just the minified CSS file for a specific Component instead of importing the entire framework.

Comment: Hi there! Can you explain what you mean? I ask because isn’t the .min file, still just the entire library?

Comment: Hello! This is how I did it:  `import { Button, Form } from "semantic-ui-react";
import "semantic-ui-css/components/button.min.css";
import "semantic-ui-css/components/form.min.css";` In this way you only import the related CSS classes for each component.